# jQuery DataTable return PHP script with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I currently have this function below:

```
 function renderDataTable(serviceUrl)
 {
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "ajax": serviceUrl
   });
 };
```

When the page is ready, I use this to send the url to set the table:

```
 renderDataTable('api/qnams_all.php');  // api/qnams_all.php is the serviceUrl
```

I'm trying to send some values to a PHP script and return the records entered by the user:

```
 $('#searchSubmit').on('click', function (){
   var searchbooking = $('#searchbooking').val();
   var searchquote = $('#searchquote').val();

   $.post('api/qnams_test.php', {searchbooking: searchbooking, searchquote: searchquote}, function(data)
   {
     renderDataTable('api/qnams_test.php');
     // I tried to do this as well ↓↓
     // renderDataTable('api/qnams_test.php' + data);
     // not successful
   });
 });
```

In the above $.post, I am sending the parameters to a different URL.  I want to return the URL to the serviceUrl in `renderDataTable(serviceUrl)` so that the data refreshes with the new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your post is a promise function on success of the post. so what ever you echo in your php script is going to be in the "data" that is the argument to the function. Try the following and see what exactly you're getting. Then use it as needed.

```
$.post('api/qnams_test.php', {
    searchbooking: searchbooking
    , searchquote: searchquote}
    , function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         renderDataTable(d)
    });

 function renderDataTable(d){
    for(item in d){
       if (d.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
         console.log("Key is " + item + ", value is" + d[item]);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Using console.log(data), I can see the data in the console...but now how do I go about getting that data to the function, renderDataTable?

Comment: what is the format of the data ? Can you post some sample data? If it is a primitive datatype like a number or a string, you can do  `renderDataTable(data)`

Comment: The data (from within the console) appears like this:  [{
"CONCAT('\"',COALESCE('',''),'\"')":"\"\"",
"CONCAT('\"',COALESCE(booking,''),'\"')":"\"NAM2262583\"",
"CONCAT('\"',COALESCE(quote,''),'\"')":"\"QNAM048212\""}]

Comment: Try the following code `var d = data[0];
renderDataTable(d);` and in the function do...
    `console.log(d["CONCAT('\"',COALESCE(booking,''),'\"')"]);`

Comment: Damn...so close...it's funny because I have input values linked to the datatable, and when added the code you suggested, and made a few other adjustments, the value I entered now appears in the input fields on the datatable.  SMH...I'll keep working on this.

Comment: I have just added some more code in the original answer. That will give you a clearer picture.

Comment: if you think that has helped you solve your issue, it is a good idea to mark the posted answer as an accepted answer. If you still have any questions, you may feel free to ask.